# Convert pom to gradle for Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

Im trying to convert an autogenerated pom.xml from (https://start.spring.io) online tool to gradle.

I have Java gradle project that needs some features in Spring boot.

(https://start.spring.io) online tool generates this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>gov.nasa.jpl.ccsds.oais.if_prototype</groupId>
    <artifactId>OaisInteropFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OaisInteropFramework</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After issuing "gradle init", based on this blog (https://howtodoinjava.com/gradle/convert-maven-project-to-gradle-project/) the pom.xml is suppose to be converted to gradle projet.

**It seems several gradle files are created however gradle.build is empty & there is an error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init'.
> Could not convert Maven POM C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test_pom\pom.xml to a Gradle build.
   > Unable to create Maven project model using POM C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test_pom\pom.xml.
      > 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.abc.defccsds.oais.if_prototype:OaisInteropFramework:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.0.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
         for project com.abc.defccsds.oais.if_prototype:OaisInteropFramework:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT at C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test_pom\pom.xml
```

How can I get back a proper gradle.build from pom , hopefully automatically using `gradle init`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not just to generate a new Gradle project from Initializr?

Comment: Problem is that gradle could not fetch artifacts because maven central repository requires https . To fix this problem try defining repository tag in your pom and use https "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" Ref: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html, in error it clearly says "ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required"

Comment: @user2880879, so do I need to create ssl key on my side, etc.. based on https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html. Is there a rep that doenst require https?

Comment: Just create a gradle project and use the gradle wrapper to run the scripts (or use a recent version of gradle if you want to use a global gradle installation). The scripts provided by the initializer work, at least with the gradle wrapper supplied with it.

Comment: The release given `2.4.0.RELEASE` does not exist yet...the most recent version of Spring Boot is `2.3.0.RELEASE`...

Comment: You don't have to create ssl key, but define maven repositories within pom and use https not http , Just look at <repositories> section of the example pom here https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#the-super-pom